# Action cable direct connection (Expected HTTP 101 response but was '404 Not Found' + Failed to upgrade to WebSocket)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm trying to open a direct websocket connection to the route of my action cable.  Unfortunately that's not working.  I'm only getting this error when curling or just hitting `http://localhost:3000/cable` directly..

```
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-06 20:04:08 -0600
Started GET "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-06 20:04:08 -0600
Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive, HTTP_UPGRADE: )
Finished "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-06 20:04:08 -0600
```

This is the exception in my client:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Expected HTTP 101 response but was ‘404 Not Found’
```

But if I hit `http://localhost:3000/page/index` with a browser, I see the following output:

```
Started GET "/page/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-06 20:05:30 -0600
Processing by PageController#index as HTML
  Rendering page/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered page/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 25.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-06 20:05:30 -0600
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-06 20:05:30 -0600
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb:12
Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vd2hvcy1yZWFkeS1hcGkvVXNlci8z)
RoomChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
RoomChannel is streaming from room_channel
RoomChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
RoomChannel is streaming from room_channel
```

Here are the relevant files, let me know if I need to share more:

```
#routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount API::Base, at: '/'

  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable/chat'

  get 'page/index'
  root 'page#index'
end
```

```
#page_controller.rb
class PageController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

I'm trying to get a connection to the websocket simply by curling to the ActionCable server route.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was not sending an `Origin` header on the http request so `allowed_request_origins` couldnt match anything.  Because of that, it was giving this super obscure error message about not being able to convert the http connection to a websocket one.